# Running simple website through Jar file

Tags: java, html, browser

I am trying to run simple static website through Jar file but not having too much luck. 
The reason I want to run the website through Jar because I don't want end users to access my pages directly. For example, they should not have access to index.html page directly without actually starting my program which is built using java swing.

Things I tried:

- Jar application works if I am running on the same machine where I created Jar using Eclipse because index.html page is fetching the page from local directory. which i know is wrong.
- If I try using different laptop or desktop then my swing application does not open any kind of index.html through my browser.

So any suggestions?

Also, I was using `Desktop.open()`, `Desktop.browse`, `getClass().getResources().getURL()` .. stuff that I seen on other pages.

Comment: *"So any suggestions?"*  Don't be so silly about 'your' HTML.  Either remove it from the net or make it easily accessible.

Comment: Just let JAR copy files to user dir or temp dir and open from there.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I actually do not want to give them my html files. The static website I will be giving them is proprietary website with multi files that include javascript, css, and html files. Actually, we are giving away our clients new laptops with local website installed so that they can get training on our material. However, after one year of initial use I want to delete our proprietary website from their laptops therefore, I was designing the Jar file application to keep track of when to initiate clean up. Also, those clients does not have access to internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy your data or use a server like tomcat, jboss etc.

Comment: I will consider using tomcat for this kind of problem.